# "gps" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission

Tags: java, android

I swear I've double checked permissions and restarted the emulator.

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="xxx.xxxx.gpsutility">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

</manifest>
```

This is the code that is the cause of the security exception (the last line):

```
protected void requestUpdates(long minTime, float minDistance) {

    // Initialize result list.
    mRecordedLocations = new ArrayList<Location>();

    // Initialize location listener.
    mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (mRecordedLocations.size() == 1) {
                makeText("Received first location");
            }
            mRecordedLocations.add(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };

    // Request location updates.
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minTime, minDistance, mLocationListener);
}
```

The method is implemented inside a fragment and it is protected because I subclass the fragment in order to have easy access to gps in other fragments. Could this be an issue?

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on, and what is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: "minSdkVersion 19" and "targetSdkVersion 23" according to my gradle file